# How to solve eslint error issues for Ant design in react

Tags: reactjs

I am working on Ant design react in this when I am running in my project then in browser it is showing error like this Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the `=>`  arrow-body-style.
I am not able to understand how to solve this error

This is my code App.js

```
/* eslint-disable eol-last */

import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Row, Col } from "antd";
import "./Walkin.css";


const Walkin = () => {
  return (
    <div className="mainDiv">
      <Row>
        <Col className="main" span={6}>
          <h1 className="hai">Hi</h1>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Walkin;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the const is returning html only, your code should be as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import './Walkin.css';


const Walkin = () => (
  <div className="mainDiv">
    <Row>
      <Col className="main" span={6}>
        <h1 className="hai">Hi</h1>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </div>
);

export default Walkin;
```

No need to add { if its only returning html

Answer (score 0):

No need of the curly braces. It is only needed if you want to have a variable or do something before returning the HTML content

```
const Walkin = () => {
          const someVal = getVal();
          return <div className="mainDiv">
              <Row>
                <Col className="main" span={6}>
                  <h1 className="hai">Hi</h1>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <p>{someVal}</p>
            </div>
        };
```

This should work

```
   const Walkin = () => (
      <div className="mainDiv">
          <Row>
            <Col className="main" span={6}>
              <h1 className="hai">Hi</h1>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
    );
```

Ref:- https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style